# Optimize Spring-Data JPA queries

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I am looking for possible optimizations for framework-generated queries.
As far as I understand, the process is the following:

- you could declare your domain objects as POJOs and adding several annotations like `@Entity`, `@Table`, `@ManyToOne`etc.
- you declare your repositories e.g. per interfaces

With (2) you have several options to describe your query: e.g. per Methodnames or `@Query`

If I write a query like:

```
@Query("select t from Order t LEFT join fetch t.orderPositions where t.id = ?1")
Page<Order> findById(Pageable pageable, String id);
```

a SQL-query is autogenerated, where every column of the order is resolved and subsequentially for orderpositions and depending obejcts/tables.
As if I wrote:

```
select * from order
```

So in case, that I need *some* Information from *several* joined objects, a query could be quite expensive: and more interesting quite ineffective. I stumbled upon a slow query and MySQL-explain told me, that in the *generated* query the optimizer could not make use of indices, which is bad.

Of course (I am aware) I have to deal with a tradeoff, that *generated* SQL isn't as optimal as *manually* written and have the advantage of writing less boilerplate code.

My question is: what are good strategies to improve queries, queryexecution?

I have thought for some options by myself:

1) Is it possible to define several "Entities" for different purposes, like `Order` for access to the *full* characteristics of an order and something like `FilteredOrder` with fewer columns and no resolution of `Join-columns`? Both would reference the same tables, but one would use all of the columns and the other only some.

2)  Use `@Query(... native="true")` with a selection of all columns, which I want to use. The advantage of that would be, that I would not double my domain-objects and litter my codebase with hundreds of `Filtered`-Objects.
What about paging? Is using `pageable` in combination with `@Query( ...native="true")` still possible (I am afraid not).

3) Last but in my eyes "worst"/boilerplate solution: Use `JDBCTemplates` and do stuff at a lower level.

Are there other options, of which I haven't thought?
Thank you for any inspiration on that topic :]

**Update:**
Our current strategy is the following

1) Where possible, I work with *select new* 
As I have [seen](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.3/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_constructor), this works for every Object (be it an *Entity* or *POJO*)

2) In combination with database *views* it is possible to take the best of *SQL* and *ORM*. For some usecases it might be of interest to have an aggregated resultset at hand. Defining this resultset as a view makes it easy from the db-perspective to watch the result with a simple *select*-statement.
For the ORM-side this means, you could easily define an entity matching this view and you get the whole *ORM-goodness* on top: Paging incl.

Comment: Firstly I would forget about optimising column reads as (unless you have tables with hundreds of columns) any performance gain is likely to be minimal: see 19.1.7 http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html. That then simplifies your model somewhat as you only need to deal with optimising associations/joins.

Comment: Thank you very much for the link! I'll have a look :] The main problem is probably the *joining* of temporary unneeded entities.

Comment: Yes, this is no doubt the biggest problem we all face when using ORM tools. There is no definitive answer to your question. I would avoid duplicating entities. Better strategy would be to write different methods in your repo e.g. findById and findByIdWithEagerXyz. Another stategy when the data is required for a screen or report could be to define a database view and map some read-only Entity to that (works just like a table). Hibernate Fetch profiles are useful 20.1.7 at the previous link (assuming you are using Hibernate) but don't know the best way of integrating these with Spring Data.

Comment: Hm. I am afraid, that there is indeed no real answer, or not a simple one. I think we are facing some limits of ORM with our project.

Comment: Like everything else. Do the simplest thing that will work which is to leave eveything lazy and optimize later once you have analyzed. For those cases where your queries are highly inefficient you can then optimize by joining, fetch profiles, db views, dtos etc. or whatever best fits the use case at hand.

Comment: I "accepted" Jakub's answer not because it is the best - I think, there is really no answer - but he gave a good answer (I didn't know "select new" before) and has the fewer points :]

Comment: What about his question on paginating a native query ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One solution is to use DTO's:

```
@Query("select new FilteredOrder(o.name, o.size, o.cost) from Order o where o.id = ?1")
Page<FilteredOrder> findFilteredOrderById(Pageable pageable, String id);
```

If you want to have entities for some reports generation maybe you should think about using nosql datastore?

Comment: That is what my first thought was: several Objects for several purposes. But so I am littering my Sourcecode. Technically I agree with you, that there is potential for NoSQL, but unfortunately I am not in charge ;)

Comment: @Jakub - How we can do the same using Lombok ?

Comment: @PAA no idea - I'm not using Lombok at all

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at JPA's lazy fetching strategy. It will allow you to select objects without their relations, but will fetch the relations when you reference them.

Comment: The problem is, that for some requests I need to resolve 3-4 joins, but sometimes only for one or two columns. I use lazy fetching as often as I could.

Comment: As @AlanHay pointed out, unless your tables have hundreds of columns, or you're retrieving hundreds of rows at a time, limiting the number of columns selected is probably a premature optimization. In practice, you probably don't need to worry about it, and writing code to deal with it will just leave you with a more complex system to maintain.

Comment: I am looking in every corner to gain speed. perhaps is the effect smaller, than I expect. What puzzles me most: I have a simple query over 180k entries. Simple task, simple SQL.Doing it manually (same tables joined, lesser columns selected) it is not only faster (1s <-> 3s), but the generated SQl is quite *inefficient*, since MySQL could not make use of (the right) index. And the only explanation I have at this point -the joins are the same- that the differing columns matter. That is only some smaller table. I have to deal with several million rows, where the speed loss is much higher than 2s.

Comment: Yes, for your use case, I would say that hand-written SQL is probably best. In my experience, the sweet spot for O/R mappers is when you are dealing with a single 'root' domain object (or just a few), and it's related hierarchy. Once you start to get into batch operations, you start start really seeing the overhead of the 'one size fits all' sql generation and the construction of lots of objects. That said, there are ways to coax JPA/Hibernate into generating more efficient sql, but it's often easier to write it yourself when it needs tuning.

Comment: Thank you for your patience and good advice:] I think in the long term, a refactoring of the infrastructure would be best: dividing "simple" operations (ORM) and "complex" ("going native"). I joined the project lately and the spirit is "doing it all with OpenJPA", which is for most operations okay, but we are getting to the limits as the project and data evolves.