# Find by many columns

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I want to perform a query like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE
col1 = 'value1' OR
col2 = 'value2' OR
col3 = 'value3' OR
col4 = 'value4';
```

Using Spring's `JpaRepository` I should use something like this:

```java
List<MyEntity> findByCol1OrCol2OrCol3OrCol4(
  String col1, String col2, String col3, String col4
);
```

**Now imagine I don't want to check 4 columns but 10 or 20**, the method name would be really long!

I have seen in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25888059/2670308) that I could use `Specification` to search the same text in many columns, but I want different text values for every one.

Is there any way to shorten the find method and add the columns (and the corresponding values) dynamically?

Thanks

Comment: Short answer is no (for `or` joins). You can use QueryDSL support to build the query dynamically.

Comment: You can use criteria and query for that. Repositories are not that good for the complex queries as specified here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17008947/whats-the-difference-between-spring-datas-mongotemplate-and-mongorepository

Comment: It seems that support for `OR` matching may be coming soon through the `Example`s API. You may want to track [this Spring Data JIRA](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1025) for release information.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved via Specifications and Map(attribute name, value). Code sample (works for any data):

```
Map<String, Object> whereClause = new HashMap<>();
whereClause.put("lastname", "Super-Lastname");
whereClause.put("firstname", "Firstńame");

userRepository.findOne(Specifications.where(
    CommonSpecifications.attributesEquals(whereClause))
)

public static <T> Specification<T> attributesEquals(Map<String, Object> whereClause) {
    return (root, query, builder) -> builder.or(root.getModel().getDeclaredSingularAttributes().stream()
            .filter(a -> whereClause.keySet().contains(a.getName()))
            .map(a -> builder.equal(root.get(a.getName()), whereClause.get(a.getName())))
            .toArray(Predicate[]::new));
}
```

Comment: I like the idea but it says cannot convert java.util.function.Predicate to A[] - this happens in both your answers - please fix it