# Search all columns for matching keyword with Spring JPA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm building a rest service with Spring Boot. I've been using Spring Data JPA for the queries but I'm open to anything that will help solve my problem.

I want to find all entries in the database with a matching string, in any column.

Something along the lines of, `FindAllBy(all 20 columns)(String parameter)` or `SELECT * FROM AllColumns() WHERE parameter = "Foo";`

I have an entity with close to 20 attributes so I'd like to avoid writing all columns names in the search.

How could I do this?

Comment: spring data jps doesnt have any methods to do this. You have to write a query

Comment: @pvpkiran do queries have some way of searching all columns?

Comment: as far as I know NO

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Data - Multi-column searches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25872637/spring-data-multi-column-searches)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This URL (https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-search-language-spring-data-specifications) will help you, I have copied some code from URL to explain you.

**you need to define a criteria class**

```
public class SearchCriteria {
    private String column;
    private String operation;
    private Object value;
}
```

**Then you need to define your  search specification**

```
public class SearchSpecification implements Specification<MyEntity> {

    private SearchCriteria criteria;

    private SearchSpecification(SearchCriteria criteria){
        this.criteria =criteria;
    }

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate
      (Root<User> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {


        if (criteria.getOperation().equalsIgnoreCase(":")) {
            if (root.get(criteria.getColumn()).getJavaType() == String.class) {
                return builder.like(
                  root.<String>get(criteria.getColumn()), "%" + criteria.getValue() + "%");
            } 
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Then finally you can modify your repository by extending JpaSpecificationExecuto**r

```
public interface MyRepository 
  extends JpaRepository<User, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<MyEntity> {}
```

**Now you can create a specification for each column** for your case all twenty column

```
SearchSpecification spec1 = 
              new SearchSpecification(new SearchCriteria("column1", ":", "searchVal"));

SearchSpecification spec2 = 
              new SearchSpecification(new SearchCriteria("column2", ":", "searchVal"));

SearchSpecification spec3 = 
              new SearchSpecification(new SearchCriteria("column3", ":", "searchVal"));
```

> **Then you need to execute query like**

```
List<MyEntity> results = 
      repository.findAll(Specification.where(spec1).or(spec2).or(spec3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the only way to search string in all column 
SELECT * FROM yourTable
WHERE field1 LIKE '%value%' or field2 LIKE '%value%' ......;