# How to write a query using spring jpa to fetch all rows from a database that are matching the string we pass?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Hi I am new to spring boot. I have a table having the following attributes: id,firstName,secondName,lastName.

Now I need to write a query (in repository), to find all those rows in my table whose firstName or secondName or lastName matches with the string I am passing.

eg: if I am passing 'foo' then it should search all the three columns and return those rows having 'foo' in any of them(this is pattern matching).

How can I do that?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try like this findByFirstnameLikeOrLastNameLike(String name, String name) in repository ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Data - Multi-column searches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25872637/spring-data-multi-column-searches)

Comment: @AbinashGhosh i tried it.. and i got this error:   Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List com.example.project.core.repository.PersonRepository.findByFirstNameLikeOrLastNameLike(java.lang.String)! null: NoSuchElementException

Comment: I just give you a example not exact query and try my answer bellow by changing as you want

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Like` query on multiple column like this way

```
public interface UserRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User,Long> {

    @Query(value="select u from User u where u.firstName = %searchtext% or u.lastName= %searchtext% or u.secondName= %searchtext%")    
    Page<User> findByAllColumns(@Param("searchtext") String searchtext, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try with the below code

```
public List<Employee> findByFirstNameIgnoreCaseContainingOrSecondNameIgnoreCaseContainingOrLastNameIgnoreCaseContaining(String firstName,String secondName,String lastName);
```