# Spring data jpa, jparepository returning list of string in place of DTO object

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a `interface` implementing **`JPARepository`** and have three methods, one of them is having a custom `@Query`.

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {

  List<Person> getPersonBycountryCode(String countryCode);

  List<Person> findByCountryCodeAndCity(String string,String city);

  @Query(value = "SELECT person.firstName as firstName, person.lastName as lastName, person.countryCode as country, person.city as city,"
              + " SQRT(POWER((69.1 * (person.age - :age )) , 2 )"
              + " + POWER((53 * (person.experience - :experience )), 2)) as eligibility"
              + " FROM Person person"
              + " ORDER BY eligibility ASC")
  List<PersonDetailsDto> findPersonDetailsByEligibility(
          @Param("age") BigDecimal age,
          @Param("experience") BigDecimal experience,
          Pageable pageable
  );
}
```

**Problem is:** method with `@Query` does not return list of `PersonDetailsDto` but return list of list of strings (**`List<List<String>>`**).

`PersonDetailsDto` is a POJO class with all the variables described in a query output **(firstName, lastName, country, city, eligibility)** and also a constructor with all the variables as Parameters. Other two methods does return list of Person object.

Any idea?

Comment: Firstly some of that syntax is invalid JPQL (POWER, SQRT). Secondly you haven't specified a result class for the query (or used "NEW PersonDetailsDto(...)" in the JPQL).

Comment: Is there any reason for this method not returning a `List<Person>` instead of a `List<PersonDetailsDto>`? You could just do `SELECT person FROM Person person ...` and then do the calculations in the business code.

Answer (score 4):

Actually `JpaRepository<Person, Long>` means that, you can use only Person as your dto in jpa repository methods.

For your solution you can just define your dto interface inside the repository :

```
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {

  List<Person> getPersonBycountryCode(String countryCode);

  List<Person> findByCountryCodeAndCity(String string,String city);

  @Query(value = "SELECT person.firstName as firstName, person.lastName as lastName, person.countryCode as country, person.city as city,"
              + " SQRT(POWER((69.1 * (person.age - :age )) , 2 )"
              + " + POWER((53 * (person.experience - :experience )), 2)) as eligibility"
              + " FROM Person person"
              + " ORDER BY eligibility ASC")
  List<PersonDetailsDto> findPersonDetailsByEligibility(
          @Param("age") BigDecimal age,
          @Param("experience") BigDecimal experience,
          Pageable pageable
  );

 //define the interface here
 public interface PersonDetailsDto{
   public String getFirstName();
   public String getLastName();
   public String getCountry();
   public String getCity();
   public Integer getEligibility();
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong the idea behind JPA not looking for specific fields is that is cost (efficiency wise) the same to bring one column or all columns from one row of the table.But to solve your problem you can set `nativeQuery = true` in the `@Query` annotation from a Repository class like this:

```
public static final String FIND_SOMETHING = "SELECT somethingId, somethingName FROM something";

@Query(FIND_SOMETHING, nativeQuery = true)
public List<Object[]> findSomethings();
```

I hope this will help you to resolve your problem.

Comment: i tried this, first it gave me exception stating that Pageable(dynamic paging and sorting option)  is not allowed with native query. Then i removed Pageable parameter from method but it still gave me same result List<List<String>> in place of List< PersonDetailsDto >

Answer (score 0):

You can use new keyword in query of @Query. And make sure you have the appropriate constructor for PersonDetailsDto and also change package name.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT new com.company.PersonDetailsDto(person.firstName, person.lastName, person.countryCode , person.city ,"
          + " SQRT(POWER((69.1 * (person.age - :age )) , 2 )"
          + " + POWER((53 * (person.experience - :experience )), 2)) "
          + " FROM Person person"
          + " ORDER BY eligibility ASC")
List<PersonDetailsDto> findPersonDetailsByEligibility(
      @Param("age") BigDecimal age,
      @Param("experience") BigDecimal experience,
      Pageable pageable
);
```

Similar [question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20121813/5039001).

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't worked for me. It threw an hibernate exception during build stating PersonDetailsDto class does not found. I believe there is some issue with my configurations. It looks like hibernate is not picking non-entity classes.

Comment: Give the fully qualified package name and try. Eg select new com.company.PersonDetailsDto(...)

Answer (score 0):

just call it by its alias, it worked for me like that
ex :

```
@Query(value = "SELECT person FROM Person person"
          + " ORDER BY eligibility ASC")
List<PersonDetailsDto> findPersonDetailsByEligibility(
      @Param("age") BigDecimal age,
      @Param("experience") BigDecimal experience,
      Pageable pageable
);
```

Comment: `PersonDetailsDto` isn't `Person`. I don't think this would work. Moreover, they are probably not going this route because they want to do the calculations in the `SELECT` clause